# DNN8 - Using the TermsSelector control

Tags: dotnetnuke, taxonomy

We upgraded one of our websites to DNN8 and one of our custom modules is throwing this error -

> Unknown server tag 'dnnweb:termsselector'

We originally implemented taxonomy in this module using the tutorial here - http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/131964/adding-core-taxonomy-to-your-module-part-6-ndash-exposing-in-the-user-interface

I checked DNN8 source code and found the TermsSelector control still being used the same way. Line 41 in this file - https://github.com/dnnsoftware/Dnn.Platform/blob/development/Website/admin/Modules/Modulesettings.ascx

But I am not able to use it in my custom module. When looking at DotNetNuke.Web.dll in an object browser, I don't see the TermsSelector class.

I have checked their list of breaking changes, but nothing related to this control is mentioned.

Can someone please help me find the reason of this inconsistency in behaviour? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the TermsSelector was moved to a different assembly.  In your module, it is likely registered at the top of the .ascx like this:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnnweb" Namespace="DotNetNuke.Web.UI.WebControls" Assembly="DotNetNuke.Web" %>
```

In the DNN8 example you linked, it is registered in the DotNetNuke.Web.Deprecated.dll assembly:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnnweb" Namespace="DotNetNuke.Web.UI.WebControls" Assembly="DotNetNuke.Web.Deprecated" %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! They have the dnnweb tagprefix declared twice, which threw me off.